# Optimize a list<T>.Sort(Comparer)

Tags: c#, generics, sorting, collections

I have a list which stores a lost of integers.
I don't like the default List.Sort() works, as I want the list to be ordered by size of the actual int.
So far I have this:

Oh, and the ints are stored in strings, e.g "1234". It is something I can not change.

```
public class IntComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                // If x is null and y is null, they're
                // equal. 
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // If x is null and y is not null, y
                // is greater. 
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If x is not null...
            //
            if (y == null)
            // ...and y is null, x is greater.
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // ...and y is not null, compare the 
                // lengths of the two strings.
                //
                int xInt = Convert.ToInt32(x);
                int yInt = Convert.ToInt32(y);

                if (x > y)
                {
                    // If the strings are not of equal length,
                    // the longer string is greater.
                    //
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (xInt == yInt)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the strings are of equal length,
                    // sort them with ordinary string comparison.


        //
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But to my knowledge, this is bubble-sort, correct?
What should I implement instead? Quicksort? also, I might need help writing it.

Oh and my list contains short of 2 thousand elements which stores numbers in strings

Also, I call my IComparer like this:

```
IntComparer intSort = New IntComparer();
List<T>.Sort(intSort);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to sort by the value of the integer stored as a string, you can simply do something like this:

```
numbers.Sort((x,y) => Int32.Parse(x).CompareTo(Int32.Parse(y)));
```

Comment: D'oh - almost identical, but you beat me by 3 minutes. +1 ;-p

Comment: Well there's a first time for everything :)

Comment: Do you have any clue if this is faster/slow/same compared to adding your own IComparer to the List.Sort()?
I don't know how fast Linq can be in such a situation :)

Comment: This is a comparer, it is just implemented as an anonymous method. As pointed out by ammoQ's answer the sorting algorithm and comparer are separate entities.

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't too sure what his answer meant, so I avoided it. This clarifies it up a little :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be aware that the comparer and the sort algorithm do not determine each other. So this comparer can be used with bubble-sort as well as with quicksort, heapsort or any other sort algorithm. The built-in sort algorithm of List.Sort is quicksort, according to MSDN.

Comment: Oh? But if I just call List<T>.Sort() my list does not get sorted after size of the ints at all - which I want to archive

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it a little bit further now. So with this comparer being called in my List.Sort means that I am doing quicksort, correct? and not bubblesort, which I originally thought because of how I had written my comparer

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list of strings representing ints as input and you want a sorted list of ints as output?

You seem to be doing a lot of work here to get the results you want - you could leverage some Linq to get your results like this:

using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var unsortedListOfStringsAsInts = new List<string> {"1234", "2345", "7", "9"};
            var sortedListOfInts = unsortedListOfStringsAsInts.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

            foreach (var i in sortedListOfInts)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And I wouldn't be concerned about optimising your sort algorithm manually with 2 thousand items - that's not really so many items to sort unless that's 'all' your application is doing.

Comment: It just seems like such a waste to generate/create a whole new list :)
Nah, it is only a part of my code, but I thought I should look into the issue and become better at it - It is a good idea to get the hang of sorting. I do like your LINQ solution though, and I'll look a little further into it as well

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to get a handle on sorting, no doubt about it :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the algorithm used for sorting a list is QuickSort, so you can't easily improve on that.

[`List<T>.Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

> This method uses `Array.Sort`, which
>   uses the QuickSort algorithm.

I completed the comparer:

```
public class IntComparer : IComparer<string> {

    private static int ParseInt32(string text) {
        long value = 0;
        foreach (char c in text) {
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                value = value * 10 + c - '0';
            } else {
                throw new FormatException();
            }
        }
        if (value > int.MaxValue) throw new OverflowException();
        return (int)value;
    }


    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        if (x == null) {
            if (y == null) {
                // If x is null and y is null, they're
                // equal. 
                return 0;
            } else {
                // If x is null and y is not null, y
                // is greater. 
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            // If x is not null...
            //
            if (y == null) {
                // ...and y is null, x is greater.
                return 1;
            } else {
                // ...and y is not null, compare the 
                // lengths of the two strings.
                //
                if (x.Length != y.Length) {
                    // If the strings are not of equal length,
                    // the longer string is greater.
                    return x.Length - y.Length;
                } else {
                    // compare numerically
                    int xInt = ParseInt32(x);
                    int yInt = ParseInt32(y);
                    return xInt - yInt;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:
I added a faster integer parser. As the comparer doesn't handle negative values, the parser doesn't either, which allowed for some further optimising.

Comment: Do you know if it is faster? :) I do like it though! +1

Comment: If the ParseInt32 method is faster than Int32.Parse? Yes, it's about ten times faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first convert the `string`s to a temporary list of `int` as the other code here (so far) converts the strings over and over again, for each comparison. (You could also use nullable ints if keeping the `null`s around is important). After that, you sort the list and if necessary convert back to strings.

Comment: The string parsing jumps out as the biggest performance hog, so +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example as long as you are using a .net 3.5 project (Linq)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> unorderedList = List<string>();
list.Add("3");
list.Add("5");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("10");
list.Add("-6");
list.Add("7");

List<string> orderedList = list.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```